# Is it okay to ask for feedback on your work/review here?

Tags: discussion

I am pretty sure asking for feedback on your work will not be acceptable here, because such questions are highly open ended. But I noticed there is a site for [code reviews](http://codereviews.stackexchange.com)  where you can ask for commentary (errors, typos, ineffeciencies) in your code.

I wonder if we can start the trend here since there are a lot of good people who could really do justice to the work (or maybe a seperate meta site). On the other hand, it might not fit in with the Q & A spirit of SE.

Asking for errors, and suggestions, etc. might do it, though. I mean you're not asking for general feedback, just if you have some errors, or if something sounds better. The quality of users on web forums is really questionable. On facebook, everybody just comes up with "Good Work", "Nice", "Keep it up bro" and nobody really critiques your work.

Perhaps we could chase it on Area51. What do you think?

Comment: I upvoted since it's a good question, but I don't think this is practical. There are many nuances of meaning and impression that affect the choice of words; only the author can say which is intended or would be better (and not always him).

Comment: It would be open ended without a doubt, but then so is SE Patents, Dating and Relationship site(still in proposal) and ofcourse, code review.

Comment: Think about your sample questions. They can't all be: "Does this excerpt sound better this way or like this..?" You can also check out [writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com/), which is another site on beta that might be interesting.

Comment: Asking "Are there any errors?" is specifically excluded in ELU as Proofreading. Review/Critique is accepted at Writers, as long as it fits their [criteria](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/734/whats-a-limit-of-the-text-that-you-can-ask-people-to-critique?cb=1).